# Billboarding sphere labels in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am new to OpenGL, so question could be quite silly.
I am trying to write molecule visualizer. Atoms are rendered as SphereImpostors. It is implemented according to [Lies and Impostors Tutorial](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html). Labels are rendered as bitmap textures generated from TrueType font.

The vertex shader is written as follows:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 Projection;

in vec3  sphere_position;
in float sphere_radius;
in vec4  sphere_color;
in vec2  texCoords;

out vec4 color;
out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{

    vec4 real_coords = Model*vec4(sphere_position, 1.0);
    vec4 outer = 0.5*Projection*vec4(sphere_radius, sphere_radius, real_coords.z, 1.0);

    float apply = -outer.x/3;

    vec4 shift;
    switch(gl_VertexID % 4)
    {
    case 0:
        shift = vec4(-outer.x, -outer.y, apply, 0.);
        break;
    case 1:
        shift = vec4( outer.x, -outer.y, apply, 0.);
        break;
    case 2:
        shift = vec4( outer.x,  outer.y, apply, 0.);
        break;
    case 3:
        shift = vec4(-outer.x,  outer.y, apply, 0.);
        break;
    }

    TexCoords = texCoords;
    color = sphere_color;
    gl_Position = Projection*Model*vec4(sphere_position, 1.0) + shift;
}
```

Fragment shader is very simple

```
#version 330

in vec4 color;
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D myTexture;


void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(myTexture, TexCoords).r)*color;
}
```

The problem is shown in Figure
[image]

Label textures overlay the cylinders (see marked with blue). It just means that I do not estimate Z-shift correctly. The futher sphere is, the bigger shift must be. The multiplier is found empirically.

My concept was to find the Z coordinate of the sphere in World coordinates

```
vec4 real_coords = Model*vec4(sphere_position, 1.0);
```

compute the sphere radius at this Z coordinate

```
Projection*vec4(sphere_radius, sphere_radius, real_coords.z, 1.0);
```

and then use it as a shift. Such approach is incorrect according to given picture.
I have read a lot of tutorials, but my understanding suffers from poor math and spatial imagination.
How can I estimate correct shift for the label it to be always on the surface of the sphere and does not overlay the part of the cylinder?

In the commerial visualizer, everything is fine with labels (since it works very fast, my assumption that spheres are also rendered as impostors).

[image]

Comment: This is kinda a deviation from using imposters, but my inclination would be to use real spheres. and texture the spheres with the correct labels. Then rotate the texture or the sphere so its always facing the camera. Then other geometry like the bonds will cover the labels up when theyre in front of them. 

I would be very surprised if this creates a speed problem; my wimpy macbook integrated gpu can happily rendere hundreds of thousands of triangles faster than I could want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that GPUs nowdays allow to render thousands of triangles without any problems. I will try to use "real" spheres for visualization. But it is obvious that ~200 triangle primitives for every atom is much more expensive than just one quad for impostor. And mentioned problem for impostor remains unresolved. I guess that it must be easy to solve if I understood the geometrical background. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Seems like the billboards will take a lot of flaky math which is inevitably hard to debug and change. Doesn't mean its a bad solution though. I don't have experience with imposters which is why I suggested an alternative solution that seems cleaner to me. I suggest taking your worst case molecule, and calculating how many triangles that would need, then rendering something with the same or more tris and see how responsive it is. That will let you know if its a viable solution (you may be surprised). Also I would think you could use smooth shading techniques to reduce a sphere to <200 tris.